# How to assign a value to a dynamic text input

Tags: knockout.js

**Question:** 
I have a custom numeric keyboard and a dynamic table including a QTY input. My question is what would be the best approach in order to assign the value of touched number to the random QTY input that had focus before touching any number?

**Example** https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/166/

HTML:

```
  <table class="table ">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Item</th>
              <th class="text-center">Qty</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach:ListOfScannedItems">
          <tr>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" data-bind="textInput:Item"></td>
              <td><input type="number" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput:Quantity" /></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>

 <input type="text" class="form-control margin-top-5" placeholder="type something" data-bind="textInput:scanItemInput">
 <input type="button" data-bind="click:AddItem" value="Add">

<ul id="keyboard">
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(1)}"><span class="off">1</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(2)}"><span class="off">2</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(3)}"><span class="off">3</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(4)}"><span class="off">4</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(5)}"><span class="off">5</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(6)}"><span class="off">6</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(7)}"><span class="off">7</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(8)}"><span class="off">8</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(9)}"><span class="off">9</span></li>
    <li class="symbol" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(0)}"><span class="off">0</span></li>
    <li class="delete lastitem" data-bind="click: function() {keybordClicked(-1)}">⌫</li>
</ul>
```

VM:

```
 var appVM = function(){
    var self = this;
   self.scanItemInput = ko.observable();
   self.ListOfScannedItems = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.AddItem = function () {
      self.ListOfScannedItems.push(new ScannedItemVM({ Item: self.scanItemInput()}));
      self.scanItemInput("");
    }
    self.keybordClicked = function(value){
     console.log(value);
       // how to assign this value to the input that has focused before pressing on any number 
    }
 }

 var ScannedItemVM = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Item = ko.observable(data.Item);
    self.Quantity = ko.observable("");
}
var vm = new appVM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the blur event binding on your scanned item inputs to track which control had focus last.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput:Quantity, event: {blur: $parent.onBlur}" />
```

...

```
self.lastFocused = ko.observable();
self.onBlur = function(data, event){
    self.lastFocused(data);
}
```

Then when your keyboard is clicked you can update the quantity of that input's view-model.

```
self.keybordClicked = function(value){
 console.log(value);
   // how to assign this value to the input that has focused before pressing on any number
   //console.log(self.ListOfScannedItems()[0].HasFocus());
   self.lastFocused().Quantity(value);
}
```

Updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/kyr6w2x3/167/

Comment: Thanks @Jason Spake Do you have any idea how to handle if the focus was the item input not the Qty or the main scanItemInput? I mean how to add value to different inputs not only Qty

Comment: @Mark.Ben In that case you could change the lastFocused observable to store the actual field rather than the whole ScannedItemVM. You'll have to change the binding to pass an extra parameter to the onBlur function indicating which field is being used. https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/169/